# Allowing only certain files to view by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have almost 20 pages on server, but i want only a file named abc.php, which users can watch. i want if user forcefully open the other files like //example.com/some.php .htaccess shows 403 error.

```
<Files ~ "^(?!(changepwd|login|register|remind|securitycode|registersuggest)\.php$).*(\.php)$">
AuthName "Reserved Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile path_to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile path_to/.htgroup
Order Deny,allow
Require group allowed_groups  
</Files>
```

this is the way i am currently using, but i think there can be more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This `.htaccess`-file will only allow users to open `index.php`. Attempts to access any other files will result in a 403-error.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "index.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

If you also want to use authentication for some of the files, you may simply add the content from your current file at the end of my example.

Comment: i also want that all js, css files to be visible which are included in index.php

Comment: Try to add something like `<Files ~ "\.(js|css)$">Allow from all </Files>`

Comment: how to allow  more than 1 file? like index.php and register.php?  in `<Files "index.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>`

Comment: This will also allow any `index.php` in subdirectories. Is there a way to make the `Allow from all` only apply to the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

Its safest to move the files you don't want the users to access to a directory which is not in the root directory of the web server.

Like if the root directory of my site is this:

```
/var/www/html/my_web_site/public/index.php
```

I can put the non-public files in another directory like this:

```
/var/www/html/my_web_site/config.php
/var/www/html/my_web_site/auth.php
/var/www/html/my_web_site/db.php
```

And include the files like this in `index.php`:

```
include("../config.php");
include("../auth.php");
include("../db.php");
```

Whit this, you don't have to risk to accidentally delete or forget to copy the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: no, i don't want this. suppose i have 10 php files independent of each other. i want my client be able to only open abc.php and all rest php files shows forbidden error on connecting.

Comment: Do you also want the login? Or is it enough with an 403-error?