# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file from my website using an URL. This is my code:

```
URLConnection download = url.openConnection();
download.addRequestProperty(
"User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

I have set the useragent, which I thought would fix the problem. Apparantly not... Perhaps I did it wrong? Need solutions :)

Comment: You may need to edit the server's configuration file to allow for external connections. The Apache web server's configuration file is named `.htaccess`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937009/htaccess-where-is-located-when-not-in-www-base-dir#answer-6937042 for help locating it in linux.

Comment: I found the file now. Using trentahost.com service. Not sure what to write inside it to tho

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617351/allowing-only-certain-files-to-view-by-htaccess

Comment: I tried to do <Files "version.html">
    Allow from all
</Files> Didnt work

Comment: Ensure that `version.html` is in a directory with the proper permissions. In this case, that directory would be `public_html`.

Comment: Hmm didnt seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

403 Means forbidden... are you sure you don't need some kind of basic authentication in your headers or anything like that?

I would suggest you to try first to call the URL you want to check with some kind of web browser http client ( Advanced Rest Client for Chrome is pretty good - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US - but any other is fine ), and try first to call from there. In that way, you can quickly figure out if the headers or anything from your request is wrong before fighting with your code.